# error while using NSVlaueTransformer to transform image to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c

this's  my PictureDataTransformer.m

```
#import "PictureDataTransformer.h"

@implementation PictureDataTransformer

+(Class)transformedValueClass
{
return [NSData class];
}

+(BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation
{
  return YES;
}

-(id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
    return UIImagePNGRepresetation(value); 
}
```

error
    Implicit declaration of function 'UIImagePNGRepresetation' is invalid in C99
    Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

```
-(id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:value];
}
```

error 2
   Use of undeclared identifier 'UIImage'
     return image;

```
@end
```

and I have 2 errors
and I don't know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've made a typo in `UIImagePNGRepresentation` - you're missing an "n".

Also, the undeclared identifier issue makes me think that you haven't imported `UIKit`.